# Is there a way to combine columns without union?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have two tables: `Monitor(size, price)` and `Laptop(size, price)` and I want to combine the data, without having columns like size1, size2. Concatenation is not what I'm after and I'm not allowed to use `union` in my assignment. I have tried different `join` operators but can't get them to work.

What I'm after:

[image: What I'm after]

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.  You've explained what you don't want.  What do you want?

Comment: "I can't use unions" - explaining the *reasons* why you can't use the obvious feature can be very helpful for would be answerers - what if they post an answer that runs into exactly the same limitation? It turns into a not fun game where the answerers have to deduce constraints that you already know.

Comment: Why can't you use unions? Your question seems artificial since UNION may be the natural solution for it.

Comment: Seeing your sample data, `union all` looks like your best pick here. You need to explain why you wouldn't want to use it.

Comment: @TheImpaler    I agree that UNION is the best and simplest solution, but my uni assignment forbids using set operators for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a `UNION ALL`, as in:

```
select size, price from laptop
union all
select size, price from monitor
```

If you don't think `UNION` is a solution, you'll need to give us a good explanation about it.

Comment: I agree with you that UNION is the best option, but I'm not allowed to use set operators in my assignment

Comment: if UNION is prohibited, is writing a temporary table allowed ? 
Or in what chapter is this exercise given ? (as your teacher is probably blocking an obvious route to teach you another construct)